# how to change default validation message from MVC3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem with code below, the easiest way for me would displaying popup message
and leave validation as is but somehow cannot figure out how to display info message straight from the controller without returning view. I know it's bad practice but in my case would be easiest thing to do.
Current code validates that one field and fails it (good) but gives default generic message. I'd like to change that message or display popup with additional info.

```
public ActionResult IsValidName(string param1)
        {
        //some code...
            var result = (count == 0);
            if (!result)
        //Popup Message(Record Exists!) and proceed

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have tried :

```
    if (!result)
        return Json(new JsonResult { "Record already   exists",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but have no idea how to intercept that new Json return in my validation javascript
where default message come from.

Answer (score 0):

Really not enough information provided, but I'll outline the correct way to do this.

If you have a form that needs to call out to your application to validate a particular field then you can conveniently mark the field property in your model like this:

Model

```
[Remote("ActionName", "Controller", ErrorMessage = "The name is not available")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult IsValidName(string param1)
{
        //some code...
            var result = (count == 0);
            if (!result)
        //Popup Message(Record Exists!) and proceed

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.CompanyName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=> x.CompanyName)
```

This is the nice built in framework way to do this. It will display the error message on the page. If you really want to do an alert box you could write your own jQuery function to check keyup on the field, call this controller action to validate and then depending on the result display your alert. Really suggest not doing that.

Comment: thanks Nick, I'd love to go that route but the problem is I that particular view is created with javascript plus some telerik controls and I don really have idea where I could put that [REMOTE] attribute...

Answer (score 0):

ok, I went with Ajax route and added in javascript callback function to actionresult
and works fine.